# Interval of convergence question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$f\left(x\right) = \frac{3}{2x-1},\; c = 2$$

The power series is centered at 2, determine the interval of convergence.

I get (same with answer sheet) this geometric series: $$f\left(x\right) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{-2}{3}\left(x-2\right)\right]^n$$

I have $r = \frac{-2}{3}\left(x-2\right)$ but the answer sheet has $r = x -2$.

Did I miss something?

I get (1/2, 7/2) for the interval.

Comment: The answer sheet is wrong. How could $x$ enter in the expression of radius??? Quick check: radius is distance from center to nearest pole, here $1/2$. Of course you must have $r > 0$.

Comment: Or maybe I missed something, what's your $r$ here? And also, are you studying power series with real, or complex variable? It doesn't change much, except maybe vocabulary (why *interval* of convergence?). Usually, convergence happens in a disc in complex plane, whose *radius* is called *radius of convergence*.

Comment: @arbutjc Geometric series $\frac{a}{1-r}$

Comment: Ok, then you may write $f(2+t)=\frac{3}{2(2+t)-1}=\frac{1}{1+2t/3}$, or $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-2(2-x)/3}$. And your $r$ is right. But that does not tell you much about convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've at last understood your approach.
Now you have the expression of $r=-\frac{2}{3}(x-2)$. You will use the series $\frac{1}{1-r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$, so you must look for $x$ values that make $|r|<1$, so that this series converges.

$$|-\frac{2}{3}(x-2)|<1$$
$$\frac{2}{3}|x-2|<1$$
$$|x-2|<\frac{3}{2}$$
$$-\frac{3}{2}<x-2<\frac{3}{2}$$
$$2-\frac{3}{2}<x<\frac{3}{2}+2$$
$$\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{7}{2}$$

So your series converges for $x \in ]\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2}[$. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: what did you mean by pole before?

Comment: This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29
It's quite usual in complex analysis, and it's a property, that the disk of convergence is the largest that does not hit a pole, hence an easy way to find it. But if you are not learning complex analysis, it's of no use to you. That's why I was asking about vocabulary, earlier.

Comment: @arbutjc, thanks for the link, and I always like learning mathematics on a deeper (higher) level.

Comment: You can first have a look at Wikipedia, reading from link to link you will find much on the subject. If you're looking for a book on complex analysis, I may give you some advice, if you know approximately the level you aim at. If you have a universiy library not too far, it's still better to have a look first :-)

Comment: My level is entry and the local library is in a different language than I can understand, so if you know of a good online resources that would be great.